# Office 365 API with my server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office365api

Can we use Office 365 API to open the file from my server and also edit using Office Online and back save to my server?
Is this possible with Office 365 API?
If yes, what the way to do so in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1):

No. The Office 365 API is used to access the customer's Office 365 data( mails, calendars, contacts, users and groups, files etc.).

To integrate the Office online, you may consider use the [WOPI](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: But i came to know that egnyte is doing so well, I found in their site. [https://helpdesk.egnyte.com/hc/en-us/articles/208233668-Edit-Egnyte-Files-Using-Microsoft-Office-Online].    Can you please help me to find what exactly egnyte is using to do so.

Comment: This what egnyte says: Many of our customers rely on Microsoft Office to stay productive. Microsoft's Office 365 for Business subscriptions include Office Online, an online version of popular applications like Word, PowerPoint, and Excel.

That's why we’re excited to announce Egnyte for Microsoft Office Online, which lets users open Office files into Office Online directly from Egnyte's web interface. Any changes made will automatically be saved back to Egnyte. This means you can edit files natively in Office without needing anything more than a web browser.